# Custom JS Prompt Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt

I'm looking for a way to customise the JS prompt popup so that I can give the user the options that I want them to have -

1. Change - Take the value from the prompt box and change the value that was checked to initiate the prompt in the first place.
2. Continue - Don't care, continue with the original value.
3. Cancel - Forget this, just get rid of the box.

Options 1 & 3 are available by default (albeit with option 1 being called 'Ok'), but I am unaware of a way to manipulate the prompt to offer a 3rd option.

I'm guessing that this cannot be done through JS, so are there any jQuery plugins that may help me? Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably need to create a [modal window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) to do what you're asking.

Comment: @Aelios - I've tried amending a couple plugins that are designed more for confirmatinos, as opposed to prompts, but I've been unable to succeed.

Comment: @Duniyadnd - Thanks for the tip, will have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI has a [dialog component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) that can be used for this.

If you're looking for a less bloated solution, a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+dialog+plugin) comes up with many reusable results.

Comment: I've looked at the jQuery UI dialog component, but it didn't seem like I was able to extend it to do what I required. I will look in to it again shortly.

Comment: Ah ha, I see that there are several iterations of this, including the 'Forms' dialog. This is looking good, certainly given me a direction to look to. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing this out. I am using it fine apart from one thing - I am bringing up the dialog form when a user clicks 'Save', so to get the form to show I am having to do `e.preventDefault()`. Trouble is, after the form has been successfully validated, I need for the event that was prevented to occur. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: what is that event? it it's a simple submit, you can set a global variable that will say whether or not the form has been validated... then you simply do $('#myForm').submit() and omit the `preventDefault()` part if that variable is set to `true`

Comment: another way would be to do it all via AJAX - even the submit itself... unless it contains file elements

Comment: It's clicking 'Publish' in Wordpress that is the event, so I'm a little tied on editing. The global variable sounds viable, although not desirable. I was also thinking of adding a hidden `<input>` with the value `0`, then setting it to `1` if all the tests are passed, followed finally by `$('#myForm').submit()` (with the test you mentioned on the `<input>` value, rather than a global).

Answer (score 3):

You're right, you can't customize the browser's prompt box:
Here is a jquery ui plugin that will help you make modal windows:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog/dialog#options

You might also use and customize (extend) this:

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Comment: Thank you, I will look in to this.

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin, i think you can change everything u need: [jAlert](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bmmage/customAlert

jquery plugin that allows for customization of Alert windows and slide down alert boxes.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
```

```css
.but{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
input{width: 100%;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Enter any text</p>
  <input type="text" /><br><br>
  <div>
    <div class="but butt1"><button>Change</button></div>
    <div class="but butt2"><button>Continue </button></div>
    <div class="but butt3"><button>Cancel </button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```